# changing background color after merging videos using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

i am putting 2 movies side by side and i want to change the background color in the spaces that left near them.

this command is taking 2 videos and placing then one on top the other. there is a gap between them and also margins from all sides. i want that all the gaps ( the rectangle that hosts the videos) will be in a specific color(it is now green, i think its the default)

```
ffmpeg -threads 11 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex 
[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=yellow[a]; 
[1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=red[b];
nullsrc=size=1080x1080[base];[a]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=666x500[top];
[b]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=666x500[bottom];
[base][top]overlay=207:35[tmp1];[tmp1][bottom]overlay=207:545[video];
[0:a]apad[apa];[1:a]apad[apa1];[apa] 
[apa1]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[audio];[2:v]scale=150:60[ovrl]; 
[video][ovrl]overlay=227:55[videoandlogo] -map [videoandlogo] -map 
[audio] -b 10000k -t 11 out.mp4
```

I want to change the default color to one that i decide. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the color filter instead of nullsrc

`nullsrc=size=1080x1080` --> `color=c=blue:size=1080x1080`

Comment: wonderful! `color` accepts `rate` just like `nullsrc`